# Do we use "the amount of" or "the number of" for mixed plural and singular nouns?

Tags: quantifiers

"the number of" precedes plural countable nouns, as in:

> "The number of **paper products**..."

"the amount of" precedes non-count nouns, as in:

> "The amount of **oil**..."

How if we want to say "the total" of both countable and uncountable nouns?
a. The number of **paper products and oil** is hard to measure.
b. The amount of **paper products and oil** is hard to measure.

Comment: You could use 'quantity', which would be appropriate for either, but you're mixing apples and oranges, and there's no good 'fruit' category here.  It's like x = 3 + 5i -- not further reducible.

Comment: @idunno Neat, if complex, analogy.

Comment: @idunno. 'Quantity' is noted. I see. Btw, I wonder if I could use 'total' as in "The total of paper products and oil..."

Comment: Again, I'd say no.  You're trying to get a common modifier for two different things.  Even if a common word would technically work for each alone, it'll be awkward at best to have it modify countable and uncountable simultaneously.  The implication is that they are, together, subject to a single measurement -- which is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they require separate quantifiers, you can either use both "the number of paper products and the amount of oil are hard to measure..." or just use "the amount" which is good for both: "The amount of paper products and oil are hard to measure..."

Comment: Yes. 'The number of people and amount of food required have doubled' doesn't 'simplify'. And in this case, replacing 'number [of paper products]' with 'amount' changes the sense.

Comment: In addition to 'amount' changing the sense, I think you'd preferably use 'amounts' rather than 'amount' -- specifically because they are two differently measured amounts, and a singular 'amount' implies a single measurement.